# Second derivative of $\frac{\ln t}{\sqrt t}$ and derivative of $\arccos(1-2x^2)$

Tags: derivatives

1. $f(t)=\dfrac{\ln t}{\sqrt t}$

I'm stuck on the algebra of finding the second derivative.

For the first derivative, I got:

$f'(t)=\dfrac{t^{\frac{-1}{2}}(1-\frac{1}{2}\ln t)}{t^2}$

For the second derivative, I'm stuck on the algebra... If someone could differentiate this and show me the steps, I'd really appreciate it.

Also:

Differentiate $y=\arccos(1-2x^2)$ with respect to x, and simplify your answer.

So far I have:

$\dfrac{-4x}{\sqrt{4x^2-4x^4}}$

Am I on the right lines?

Comment: Well, substitution always makes it easier. In the second problem, putting $x=\sin t$ would be helpful. In the first one, won't be much helpful but, try putting $t=e^y$

Comment: I've never been taught the substitution methods for differentiation, so for now I'd like to stick to methods I already know. Any other methods?

Comment: Have you been taught the chain rule?

Comment: Yes - I have, but I'm having a serious brain lag here.

Comment: There are no 'methods' for substitution. I mean, you've got to see how possibly you could simplify it. For the second problem, putting $x=sin t$ gives $arccos(1-sin^2 t)=arccos(cos 2t)=2t=2 arcsin x$, you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've made some mistakes.  As for the first one, that first derivative doesn't look right.  I've never really learned the rule for division as the product rule is much easier.

$$(t^{-1/2}\ln t)=t^{-3/2}-\frac12t^{-3/2}\ln t$$

Now repeat the process for the second derivative.  As for the second, it looks like you're close, but there are a couple problems.

$$d(\cos^{-1}t)=-\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

If $t=1-2x^2$, we have

$$-\frac{d(1-2x^2)}{\sqrt{1-(1-2x^2)^2}}=-\frac{-4xdx}{\sqrt{1-(1-4x^2+4x^4)}}=\frac{4xdx}{\sqrt{4x^2-4x^4}}$$

From here, a little simplification can be done.  If you assume $x$ is positive, the denominator can be rewritten as $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and you probably wouldn't be marked wrong if you rewrote it as such and cancelled the $x$'s.  The denominator is technically $2|x|\sqrt{1-x^2}$, but that doesn't cancel as nicely.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, writing $f(t)=t^{-1/2}\ln t$ and then using the *product* rule might help:

$$f'(t)={-1\over2}t^{-3/2}\ln t+t^{-1/2}(1/t)=t^{-3/2}(1-{1\over2}\ln t)$$

See if you can now do the second derivative in the same way.

As for the arccos problem, you made a sign mistake.  The correct answer is

$${4x\over\sqrt{4x^2-4x^4}}$$

That is, the derivative of $\arccos t$ (with respect to $t$) is $-1/\sqrt{1-t^2}$.  You can simplify this to

$$2x\over|x|\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

but not to

$$2\over\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

unless the problem tells you that $x\gt0$.  In other words, as nice-looking as $\arccos(1-2x^2)$ seems to be, it does not have a derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: But surely using the quotient rule here is still fine? Low d high minus high d low over low squared... Not sure why but I have a preference for it. I'll try the product rule for this one then, thanks.

Comment: @Jim, yes, the quotient rule is OK to use, you just wind up with more clean-up to do.  Also, if you compare what you got for $f'(t)$ with what I got, you'll see that one of us made a mistake, because I got a $t^{-3/2}$ and you got (in effect) a $t^{-5/2}$.  Which one of us do you think is wrong?

Comment: Ah, that was me being silly, I squared $t$ instead of $\sqrt t$

Comment: I tried it and got $t^{-5/2}(-3/2(1-0.5 \ln t)+0.5)$... correct?

Comment: @Jim, I get a $-0.5$ at the end, or $(3\ln t-8)/(4t^{5/2})$ in all.